# 2D Numpy Array of Strings WITH column access

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, matplotlib

New to Python and `Numpy` and `MatPlotLib`.

I am trying to create a `2D` `Numpy` array from a `CSV` of various data types, but I will treat them all as strings. The killer is that I need to be able to access them with `tuple` indices, like: `[:,5]` to get the 5th column, or `[5]` to get the 5th row.

**Is there any way to do this?**

It seems that this is a limitation of `Numpy` due to the memory-access calculations:

```
dataSet = np.loadtxt(open("adult.data.csv", "rb"), delimiter=" ,")
print dataSet[:, 4] <---results in IndexError: Invalid Index
```

I have also tried `loadfromgen`, `dtype = str` and `dtype = "a16"`, as well as `dtype = object`. Nothing works. I can either load the data and it does not have column access, or I can't load the data at all.

Comment: Your delimiter is `" ,"`. Is that actually what separates elements in each row of your input file? A space, *then* a comma?

Comment: Yes there is also a space. I could just use a comma, but it doesn't matter.
Edit: Or at least I don't think it matters....

Comment: What are `dataSet.shape` and `dataSet.dtype`?

Comment: You need to examine `dataSet`.  Print some rows, print the shape and dtype.  Don't jump into indexing before you know what you have got.  A sample of the csv file might also help us diagnose your problem.

Comment: The rows are very clean, all look like this. About 32,000 lines.

39, State-gov, 77516, Bachelors, 13, Never-married, Adm-clerical, Not-in-family, White, Male, 2174, 0, 40, United-States, <=50K

Comment: What shape and dtype do you get with `delimiter=','` and `dtype=None`?  Any column headers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simulate you file from the comment line - replicated several time (i.e. one string per row of the file):

```
In [8]: txt = b" 39, State-gov, 77516, Bachelors, 13, Never-married, Adm-clerical, Not-in-family, White, Male, 2174, 0, 40, United-States, <=50K"
In [9]: txt = [txt for _ in range(5)]

In [10]: txt
Out[10]: 
[b' 39, State-gov, 77516, Bachelors, 13, Never-married, Adm-clerical, Not-in-family, White, Male, 2174, 0, 40, United-States, <=50K',
 b' 39, State-gov, 77516, Bachelors, 13, Never-married, Adm-clerical, Not-in-family, White, Male, 2174, 0, 40, United-States, <=50K',
 b' 39, State-gov, 77516, Bachelors, 13, Never-married, Adm-clerical, Not-in-family, White, Male, 2174, 0, 40, United-States, <=50K',
 b' 39, State-gov, 77516, Bachelors, 13, Never-married, Adm-clerical, Not-in-family, White, Male, 2174, 0, 40, United-States, <=50K',
 b' 39, State-gov, 77516, Bachelors, 13, Never-married, Adm-clerical, Not-in-family, White, Male, 2174, 0, 40, United-States, <=50K']
```

Load with `genfromtxt`, with delimiter.  Let it choose the best dtype per column:

```
In [12]: A=np.genfromtxt(txt, delimiter=',',dtype=None)
In [13]: A
Out[13]: 
array([ (39, b' State-gov', 77516, b' Bachelors', 13, b' Never-married', b' Adm-clerical', b' Not-in-family', b' White', b' Male', 2174, 0, 40, b' United-States', b' <=50K'),
       (39, b' State-gov', 77516, b' Bachelors', 13, b' Never-married', b' Adm-clerical', b' Not-in-family', b' White', b' Male', 2174, 0, 40, b' United-States', b' <=50K'),...], 
      dtype=[('f0', '<i4'), ('f1', 'S10'), ('f2', '<i4'), ('f3', 'S10'), ('f4', '<i4'), ('f5', 'S14'), ('f6', 'S13'), ('f7', 'S14'), ('f8', 'S6'), ('f9', 'S5'), ('f10', '<i4'), ('f11', '<i4'), ('f12', '<i4'), ('f13', 'S14'), ('f14', 'S6')])
```

5 element array with a compound dtype

```
In [14]: A.shape
Out[14]: (5,)
In [15]: A.dtype
Out[15]: dtype([('f0', '<i4'), ('f1', 'S10'), ('f2', '<i4'),
    ('f3', 'S10'), ('f4', '<i4'), ....])
```

Access a 'column' with a field name (not column number)

```
In [16]: A['f4']
Out[16]: array([13, 13, 13, 13, 13])
```

Or load as dtype=str:

```
In [17]: A=np.genfromtxt(txt, delimiter=',',dtype=str)
In [18]: A
Out[18]: 
array([['39', ' State-gov', ' 77516', ' Bachelors', ' 13',
        ' Never-married', ' Adm-clerical', ' Not-in-family', ' White',
        ' Male', ' 2174', ' 0', ' 40', ' United-States', ' <=50K'],
        ...
        ' Male', ' 2174', ' 0', ' 40', ' United-States', ' <=50K']], 
      dtype='<U14')
In [19]: A.dtype
Out[19]: dtype('<U14')
In [20]: A.shape
Out[20]: (5, 15)
In [21]: A[:,4]
Out[21]: 
array([' 13', ' 13', ' 13', ' 13', ' 13'], 
      dtype='<U14')
```

Now it is 15 column 2d array that can be indexed with column number.

With the wrong delimiter, and it loads one column per row

```
In [24]: A=np.genfromtxt(txt, delimiter=' ,',dtype=str)
In [25]: A
Out[25]: 
array([ '39, State-gov, 77516, Bachelors, 13, Never-married, Adm-clerical, Not-in-family, White, Male, 2174, 0, 40, United-States, <=50K',
      ...], 
      dtype='<U127')
In [26]: A.shape
Out[26]: (5,)
```

A 1d array with a long string dtype.

A CSV file might loaded in various ways, some intentional, some not.  You have to look at the results, and try to understand them before blindly trying to index columns.

Comment: WOW! Thanks so much for all that work. Through it I was able to solve it and everything is happy now. :)